# Print out key/value of an object

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have an array

---

## dd($vcpe)

```
array:23 [▼
  "cpe_mac" => "436291229311"
  "bandwidth_max_up" => 0
  "bandwidth_max_down" => 0
  "filter_icmp_inbound" => false
  "dmz_enabled" => false
  "dmz_host" => "192.168.1.1"
  "vlan_id" => 2
  "dns" => array:1 [▼
    0 => ""
  ]
  "xdns_mode" => 0
  "cfprofileid" => 11111
  "stub_response" => "0"
  "acl_mode" => 0
  "portal_url" => ""
  "fullbandwidth_max_up" => 1000000
  "fullbandwidth_max_down" => 2000000
  "fullbandwidth_guaranty_up" => 300000
  "fullbandwidth_guaranty_down" => 400000
  "account_id" => 1001
  "location_id" => 3333
  "network_count" => 3
  "group_name" => "test_group"
  "vse_id" => 20
  "firewall_enabled" => false
]
```

---

I want to loop through it, and print out the key, and the value.

## Try#1

```
        @foreach ($vcpe as $key => $value)
          <p>{{$key}} : {{$value}}</p>
        @endforeach
```

I got

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

---

## Try#2

```
        @foreach ($vcpe as $key => $value)
          <p>{!!$key!!} : {!!$value!!}</p>
        @endforeach
```

I got

```
Array to string conversion
```

---

## Try#3

```
        @foreach ($vcpe as $key => $value)
          @foreach ($key as $k => $v)
            <p>{{$k}} : {{$v}}</p>
          @endforeach
        @endforeach
```

I got

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

What did I do wrong ?

How can I fix it ?

Can someone please show how do I print out all my key/value of an object ?

Comment: First can you do a `print_r($vcpe)` back in the controller, so we can see what this data structure really looks like. Paste the result into _your question_

Comment: please do what @RiggsFolly says

Comment: In Try 2, one of the values is an array. You tried to print it as a string and got the appropriate error. In Try 3, many values are not arrays, so you can't use foreach to go over them. You need to check to see if the value is an array or not and then do the appropriate task.

Comment: try like `$newArray = (array)$vcpe;` ande then use `foreach`

Comment: @A-2-A : Ok, let me try that.

Comment: convert object to array first, and then loop it using foreach, to convert object to array, you use $array =  (array) $yourObject; this

Comment: Thanks all. I'm trying it now.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make the `print_r()` readable **not** Never mind I did it for you

Comment: You beat me. I'm in the process of making it pretty.

Comment: I have the feeling, that it's not the object but the value of $vcpe->dns, which is an array. Can you loop without errors when removing `{{$value}}`??

Comment: What do you mean removing `{{$value}}` ? Loop through key only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, $value could be an array. You didn't loop only through the keys only unfortunately, so I can't be sure. But I urge you to try this:

```
@foreach ($vcpe as $key => $value)
    @if (is_array($value))
        <p>{{$key}} :
        @foreach ($value as $value_key => $value_value) 
            {{$value_value}} 
        @endforeach
        </p>
    @else
        <p>{{$key}} : {{$value}}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```